# Open BottomNavigation Fragment From Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i have to open bottom navigation fragment from one activity so how can i open to this?
So how to pass Flag and open 4th number of bottomnavigation fragment open??

```
val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()
profileFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, profileFragment.tag)


val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()
val navController = findNavController(R.id.btm_home)
navController.navigate(R.id.btm_profile)


       val manager: FragmentManager = fragmentManager
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.add(R.id.container, , YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
```

Comment: can explain more about to question

Comment: i have to open bottom navigation fragment from one activity so how can i open to this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment fragment2 = new DashboardFragment();
final Fragment fragment3 = new NotificationsFragment();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = fragment1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment1, "1").commit();

}


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                active = fragment1;
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                active = fragment2;
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                active = fragment3;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```